# Connecting Django's Admin Users to Model

Tags: django

Let's say I have a two models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField()
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Member {self.nickname}'

class Dashboard(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here I create a distinct model for tracking members who can edit dashboards. Can I use Django users for that instead, avoiding creation of my own models?

Comment: In short, yes you can. Just use `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` to import User model and use it as FK.

Comment: That's right. But, there will be errors if you were already extended the auth model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Just use [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) as your related reference as,

```
from django.conf import settings


class Dashboard(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # rest of your models
```

**Note:** You can also import the **built-in `User` model** from `django.contrib.auth.models` as `@ruddra` mentioned, But, there will be errors if you were already extended the auth model.

Comment: If I want to add my custom attributes, I need to inherit from AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Comment: Yes. Here you can find the official doc, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model